# Find the angle between two vectors p and q, if |p x q| = p.q

Tags: vectors, cross-product

Find the angle between two vectors **p** and **q**, if **|p x q| = p.q**

Comment: What have you tried? [Context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that $\mathbf{p},\mathbf{q}\neq0$. Let $\theta$ be the angle between $\mathbf{p}$ and $\mathbf{q}$.

Since $\|\mathbf{p}\times\mathbf{q}\|=\|\mathbf{p}\|.\|\mathbf{q}\|.\sin\theta$ and $\mathbf{p}.\mathbf{q}=\|\mathbf p\|.\|\mathbf q\|.\cos\theta$, the angle is such that $\sin\theta=\cos\theta$. Since $\theta\in[0,\pi]$, the only possible value of $\theta$ is $\frac\pi4$.

Comment: According to the equation given, $\cos(\theta)\ge0$, so $\frac{3\pi}4$ is out.

Comment: @robjohn Thanks. I've edited my answer.

Comment: If you define the angle between two vectors as an angle $0\le \theta\le \pi$, then $\sin\theta\ge 0$, so $|\sin \theta|=\sin\theta$.

Comment: @user236182 Yes, that's how I define it. I will edit my answer (again). Thanks.

Comment: The absolute values around sine were correct, but I guess if the angle is in $[0,\pi]$ we're okay. (+1)